# Missing views and other static files in drop folder (TFS2015 Update 3)

Tags: build, tfs-2015

I have a Teamproject which has only one solution, which contains a MVC web application and a MS Test project (Unit tests).
The Unit test project references the web app.

1. MyWebApp
2. MyWebApp.Tests

I can see all files being copied to the Build_SourceDirectory!
But I can only see the MyWebApp.Tests being copied to the Drop folder!?

---

**My Visual Studio buil step:**
[image]

---

**My Copy Files build step:**
[image]

---

**Question:**
Why does "Copy Files" build step only copy the artifacts of the test project and not the web app, which is in the same solution?
Here is the [log file](http://pastebin.com/KtcPijsj)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**` means you want to copy the files in any sub-folder under `bin\$(BuildConfiguration)`, but MyWebApp's outputs are in bin folder, not under `bin\$(BuildConfiguration)`, so they are not copied.

Specify the Contents in Copy Files task to `**\bin\**`, you'll get both outputs for MyWebApp and MyWebApp.Tests:

[image]

Comment: Ok, now I can see the MyWebApp folder. It contains dll's only. Where are the views, static files?

Answer (score 1):

**An addition to the provided answer.**

With the OOTB minimatch filter:

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**
```

you copy everything beneath the BuildConfiguration folder (Release/Debug/etc).

Web apps don't have a Debug/Release folder by default, only one **bin** folder. That's the reason why anything was copied to the drop folder.

So I had to include some content filters to include/exclude the files/folders I want to copy/don't want to copy, like this:

[image]

For exclusions you can use negated filters using the `!` sign.